# Manage Menu with jquery addClass & remove class

Tags: jquery, click, addclass

Im creating a NAVIGATION, it has 3 states. Normal, Rollover and Selected.

And each button has different images for all 3 states.
[image: naviation]

I want to do this with jQuery.

State 1 & 2 I can show with seperate class for

```
.boy1 a {background-image:...}
.boy1 a:hover {background-image:...}
.boy2 a {background-image:...}
.boy2 a:hover {background-image:...}
.boy3 a {background-image:...}
.boy3 a:hover {background-image:...}
```

But when you click on BUTTON, it should show a DIV that contains its NAME or any other image.

e.g.

```
$(".boy1").click(function() {
  $("#boy1").show("slow");
});
```

**But now my problem is, if someone clicks on other buttons earlier #boy1 DIV should hide and if you click .boy2 then #boy2 show show and other #boy1 or #boy3 should hide**

HTML PART:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="boy1"><a href="#section1"></a></div>
    <div id="boy1">MR ABC</div>

    <div class="boy2"><a href="#section2"></a></div>
    <div id="boy2">MR XYZ</div>

    <div class="boy3"><a href="#section3"></a></div>
    <div id="boy3">MR LALOLA</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .boy1 a { background-image:images/boy1.gif; display:block; cursor:pointer; height:100px; width:50px}
    .boy1 a:hover { background-image:images/boyimage1.gif;}
    #boy1 {position:absolute; top:100; left:50; height:30px; width:60px;}

    .boy2 a { background-image:images/boy2.gif; display:block; cursor:pointer; height:100px; width:50px}
    .boy2 a:hover { background-image:images/boyimage2.gif;}
    #boy2 {position:absolute; top:100; left:200; height:30px; width:60px;}

    .boy3 a { background-image:images/boy3.gif; display:block; cursor:pointer; height:100px; width:50px}
    .boy3 a:hover { background-image:images/boyimage3.gif;}
    #boy3 {position:absolute; top:100; left:350; height:30px; width:60px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Where is the name coming from/placed in HTML code?

Comment: The image/name below on SELECTED state it will be just a DIV, its html website.

Comment: HTML part i have not started yet, im gathering all sources first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="boy1"><a href="#section1">x</a></div>
    <div id="boy1" class="showhidediv">MR ABC</div>

    <div class="boy2"><a href="#section2">y</a></div>
    <div id="boy2" class="showhidediv">MR XYZ</div>

    <div class="boy3"><a href="#section3">z</a></div>
    <div id="boy3" class="showhidediv">MR LALOLA</div>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div.boy1').on('click',function(){
    $('div#boy1').siblings('.showhidediv').hide();
    $('div#boy1').show();
});

  $('div.boy2').on('click',function(){
    $('div#boy2').siblings('.showhidediv').hide();
    $('div#boy2').show();
});

   $('div.boy3').on('click',function(){
    $('div#boy3').siblings('.showhidediv').hide();
    $('div#boy3').show();
});

});
```

​[check the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxgh2/)

add `$('.showhidediv').hide();` to your code if you want to start by hiding all the divs.

I hope this will solve your problem. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Comment: But each button with have its own DIV, that will become visible on clicking it. 
What I mean is, so #boy1 will show when .boy1 is clicked and #boy2 will show when .boy2 is clicked and so on.
Thanks for reply :)

Comment: Please post your HTML code too. it will be easy for me to answer. I think I have mistaken your question

Comment: added HTML also now, see if it helps

Comment: check the new answer. I edited it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to display `#boy1` div when you click on `.boy1` element, and if you click on `.boy2` element, it should display `#boy2` div but hide other boy div.,

I am assuming that you will have only one class on your boy1 or boy2 element.

If it is you can try this.

```
$(".boy1, .boy2, .boy3").click(function() {
   var self = this;
   $('[id^=boy]').hide();
   $("#"+self.className).show("slow");
});
```

Comment: Im gona try your technique, I hope it will hide all other #boy1 or #boy2, if #boy3 is visible. and so on.